# Stack added items on JList

Tags: java, swing, jlist

I'm trying to transfer the selected items from a source JList and destination JList on button click. So what I did is this.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        int index = AddSubjectsToCurriculum.getSelectedIndex();
        String selectedItemOnSourceList = AddSubjectsToCurriculum.getSelectedValue().toString(); 
        int x = 0;

        if(index >= 0) // --if atleast 1 is selected
        {
            DefaultListModel dlm = new DefaultListModel(); //--declare a placeholder for items you will add
                dlm.add(x++,selectedItemOnSourceList); // --add the selected item to dlm 
                CurriculumSubjects.setModel(dlm); //--at this point item has been added already
            ((DefaultListModel)AddSubjectsToCurriculum.getModel()).remove(index); // --remove what was selected from source list
        }//end of if
    }
```

But everytime I click the button, it only adds the selected item from source list but never populates or updates the destination list with new elements added. How do I fix this? I need to setModel() everytime button is clicked but I need to be able to move forward to the next index on next button click.

Only adds one and shows one element for every `>` button click

[image]

I'd appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: You never add the prexisting items from the `CurriculumSubjects` to the model. Maybe instead of creating a new model, you should cast the model from `CurriculumSubjects` to a `DefaultListModel` and simply use it (assuming you set `DefaultListModel` an empty model to it begin with)

Comment: the assignment of `selectedItemOnSourceList` will provoke a `NullPointerException` if you press the button and have no element selected. This happens because you do not check, if `getSelectedValue()` returns `null` before calling `toString()` on it. But you should really only read the selected value when there is actually an item selected, so you should move the code inside the `if(index >= 0)`.